# how to properly connect receiver, sender and top and make them dependent from each other - RS232

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl

I've got a simple project which requires me to write a code for RS232 **receiver** and **sender**, then put them together and, finally, test if it works properly. I've prepared code for both **sender** and **receiver** (and also **connecting block** - **top**). My problem is that I don't know **how to connect them**, so they could **work with each other properly**.

The main issue is that I can't "transfer" data from **data_o** to **data_i** because of the fact that one is **reg** and second - **wire**. I wouldn't like to use **inout** for these purposes. I can't figure out any possible modifications to make it work.

Another issue is putting some **flags** that could kind of follow idea like this: if **receiving** -> **not sending**, if **sending** -> **not receiving**.

Here's my code:

top.v

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module top (
    clk_i,
    rst_i,
    RXD_i,
    data_i,
    TXD_o,
    data_o
);

input clk_i;
input rst_i;
input RXD_i;
output TXD_o;

//the problem is here, can't data_i <= data_o because output is reg
input [7:0] data_i;
output [7:0] data_o;

receiver r1(clk_i, RXD_i, data_o);
sender s1(clk_i, data_i, TXD_o);

endmodule
```

receiver.v

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module receiver (
    clk_i,
    RXD_i,
    data_o
);

//inputs and outputs
input clk_i;
input RXD_i;
output reg [7:0] data_o;

//counter values
parameter received_bit_period = 5208;
parameter half_received_bit_period = 2604;

//state definitions
parameter ready = 2'b00;
parameter start_bit = 2'b01;
parameter data_bits = 2'b10;
parameter stop_bit = 2'b11;

//operational regs
reg [12:0] counter = 0;  //9765.625Hz
reg [7:0] received_data = 8'b00000000;
reg [3:0] data_bit_count = 0;
reg [1:0] state = ready;

//latching part
reg internal_RXD;

always @(posedge clk_i) //latch RXD_i value to internal_RXD
    begin
        internal_RXD = RXD_i;
    end

always @(clk_i) //receiving process
    begin  
        case (state)
            ready : 
                begin
                    if (internal_RXD == 0)
                        begin
                            state <= start_bit;
                            counter <= counter + 1;
                        end
                    else
                        begin
                            state <= ready;
                            counter <= 0;
                            data_bit_count <= 0;
                        end
                end     
            start_bit :
                begin
                    if (counter == half_received_bit_period)
                        begin
                            if (internal_RXD == 0)
                                begin
                                    state <= data_bits;
                                    counter <= 0;
                                end
                        end
                    else
                        begin
                            state <= start_bit;
                            counter <= counter + 1;
                        end     

                end
            data_bits : 
                begin           
                    if (counter == received_bit_period)
                        begin
                            received_data[data_bit_count] <= internal_RXD;
                            data_bit_count <= data_bit_count + 1;   
                            counter <= 0;
                            if (data_bit_count == 8)
                                state <= stop_bit;
                        end
                    else
                        counter <= counter + 1; 
                end
            stop_bit:
                begin
                    counter <= counter + 1;
                    if (counter == received_bit_period)
                        begin
                            state <= ready;
                            data_o <= received_data;
                        end
                end
        endcase 
    end

endmodule
```

sender.v

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module sender (
    clk_i,
    data_i,
    TXD_o
);

//inputs and outputs
input clk_i;
input [7:0] data_i;
output reg TXD_o;

//counter values
parameter received_bit_period = 5208;
parameter half_received_bit_period = 2604;

//state definitions
parameter ready = 1'b0;
parameter data_bits = 1'b1;

//operational regs
reg [12:0] counter = 0;  //9765.625Hz
reg [9:0] framed_data = 0;
reg [3:0] data_bit_count = 0;
reg state = ready;

always @(posedge clk_i) //sending process
    begin
        case (state)
            ready : 
                begin // flag needed?
                    state <= data_bits;
                    TXD_o <= 1;
                    framed_data[0] <= 1'b0;
                    framed_data[8:1] <= data_i;
                    framed_data[9] <= 1'b1;
                    counter <= 0;
                end
            data_bits :
                begin
                    counter <= counter + 1;
                    if (data_bit_count == 10)
                        begin // flag needed?
                            state <= ready;
                            data_bit_count <= 0;
                            TXD_o <= 1;
                        end
                    else
                        begin
                            if (counter == received_bit_period)
                                begin
                                    data_bit_count <= data_bit_count + 1;
                                end
                            TXD_o <= framed_data[data_bit_count];
                        end     
                end
        endcase 
    end

endmodule
```

Comment: RS232 is a voltage level not a protocol.  you are saying you want to write -15Volts and +15volts or you are saying you want to send some bits serially?

Comment: I want to send some bits serially.

Answer (score 1):

You don't!
In all CPU's and FPGA nowadays the read and write data path are separate buses. You will find that also with all CPU cores. Have a look at AXI or AHB bus protocols from ARM.

What is more worrying is the way you have implemented your functions. You would at least need some 'data valid' signal for the transmitter to know when there is valid data to transmit and for the receive when valid data has arrived.
Even that is not enough because for the TX the connecting logic would need to know when the data has been send and the next byte can go out.

You need to make a (preferably standard) CPU interface which talks to your UART. (For beginner I would **not** use AXI.)

As to your flags: they would come from within the CPU interface.

Last: a UART should be capable of transmitting and receiving at the same time.

Comment: I have actually tried to impement these things in my code, unfortunately I was not successful. Probably because I'm doing something wrong. How would you solve this?

Comment: Start with a simple CPU bus model in your testbench which can simulate reads and writes. Make a UART CPU interface where you can read and write registers. There is a website that not only posts Verilog code (as many do) but also the test-benches: https://www.verilog.pro